# How to run a curl command in an Elastic Beanstalk environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to run a `curl` command periodically in Elastic Beanstalk.

I understand that by adding a `cron.yaml` file to the deployment, the leading instance can execute a URL, like so:

```
version: 1
cron:
 - name: "myJobName"
   url: "/myUrl"
   schedule: "0 2 * * *"
```

But what is the easiest way to run a `curl` command?

Comment: what is purpose of this?

Comment: making a URL call with some headers.